# Mouse left click is not binding with listbox inside a pop up wpf

Tags: .net, wpf, popup, mouseevent, event-binding

I have a pop-up and inside that I have a listbox control.I need to bind mouse left click event with items in listbox. I have written

```
<Popup StaysOpen="False" IsOpen="{Binding VisibiltyAttr}" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=InputText}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" AllowsTransparency="True"  >
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=ItemIndex, Mode=TwoWay}"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}">
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonUp">
                            <i:InvokeCommandAction  Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}, 
                                        Path=DataContext.SelectionCommand}"  CommandParameter="{Binding}"></i:InvokeCommandAction>
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Popup>
```

Before I have addded the popup the event was working fine.

Comment: Your code is working for me, Mouse left click is firing. Please show your viewmodel command.

Comment: public ICommand SelectionCommand => new DelegateCommand(() => this.GetSelectedAutoComplete());

Comment: Is your breakpoint hitting the code above?

Comment: break point is hitting to command but not the method GetSelectedAutoComplete

Comment: try removing the this?

Comment: tried removing this but Not working

Comment: If you want to work with the selecteditem why not just bind selecteditem and act in the setter of the property? https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/30564.wpf-uneventful-mvvm.aspx#Select_From_List_IndexChanged

Answer (score 0):

Use Relay Command Instead Delegate Command

**RelayCommand.cs**

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private Action<object> execute;
    private Predicate<object> canExecute;
    private event EventHandler CanExecuteChangedInternal;
    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute)
        : this(execute, DefaultCanExecute)
    {
    }
    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(execute));
        }
        if (canExecute == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(canExecute));
        }
        this.execute = execute;
        this.canExecute = canExecute;
    }
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add
        {
            CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
            CanExecuteChangedInternal += value;
        }
        remove
        {
            CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
            CanExecuteChangedInternal -= value;
        }
    }
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return canExecute != null && canExecute(parameter);
    }
    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        execute(parameter);
    }
    public void OnCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        EventHandler handler = CanExecuteChangedInternal;
        handler?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
    public void Destroy()
    {
        canExecute = _ => false;
        execute = _ => { };
    }
    private static bool DefaultCanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**YourViewModel.cs**

```
private ICommand selectionCommand;
public ICommand SelectionCommand
{
    get { return selectionCommand ?? (selectionCommand = new RelayCommand(Selected, CanSelect)); }
    set { selectionCommand = value; }
}

private void Selected(object obj)
{
}
```

Comment: Why, what makes it different?

Comment: I have tried your code by using my relay command. Its working for me, so i suggested you. If suppose your custom delegate command can create any misbehavior.

Comment: It was working fine earlier with itemscontrol. later i convert itemscontrol into listbox and also wrap it inside a popup.

Comment: Set `x:Name="myList"` into your `ListBox` and refer the myList like this, `<i:InvokeCommandAction  Command="{Binding DataContext.SelectionCommand, Source={x:Reference myList}}"  CommandParameter="{Binding}"></i:InvokeCommandAction>`

Comment: my code is working fine by replacing event name to PreviewMouseDown

Comment: but another problem is on mouse click selected item index is not changing in ItemIndex